# laravel upload image getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Tags: image, laravel, upload, null

Hello I'm getting the following error when I don't select any image into the input field: `Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null`

How do I avoid that, and how do I check if the input file field is empty so I don't run into this error with the following code?

```
$imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = 'events';
$upload_success = $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check that the request has the file you want to manipulate, using `hasFile()` method:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = 'events';
    $upload_success = $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
}
```

See Laravel documentation about [handling uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files)

Answer (score 0):

$image = $value->file('photo');

$img_name=md5(time().rand()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image->move(public_path('images'),img_name);

Comment: Hello, and welcome. As part of your answer, it'd be useful to explain what this code does and why it solves the OP's question. Also, how does your code differ from the already accepted answer? On quick glance, it appears to be repeating the same basic guidance?